# Experiences and research in motivational effect on giving bonus points in exams based on handed in exercise problems

Tags: exams, motivation

In our curriculum we have several courses that students fail a lot. One of the reasons which we suspect leads them to fail is that a lot of students do not do the exercises that we advise them to do. A possible solution we are considering, is to give students who successfully solve several exercise problems a few bonus points on the exams.

My question is:
First, do people here have experimented with such a technique? Did it work? What are the pitfalls? Is there any literature that could be helpful here?

Comment: Why not make the exercises themselves a part of the grading rubric instead of awarding points for them in the exams? Unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: It would help if you included some background about the level of students (beginning to intermediate level undergraduate, upper level undergraduate, beginning graduate level, advanced graduate level) and the type of college/university you're at (primarily teaching, liberal arts, primarily research, other including combinations of these) and the country the college/university is in. The reason I say this is that my experience is that it sounds like you're simply asking if homework should be graded and included in the assessment of student grades, which is extremely common in my experience.

Comment: Hmmm. Do you "advise" students to do exercises and then not check them and give feedback?

Comment: The obvious pitfall is that many students may not do those exercises on their own, either getting extensive help or blatantly copying, thus circumventing your goal.  My guess is that the ones who are not doing exercises anyway are the ones more likely to just copy solutions.

Comment: @justauser, We would like to allow students to also make the exam without also doing the exercisis. This especially for the students that failed the exam last year and want to do a resit this year.

Comment: @Buffy, We have experimented with just checking, and giving feedback. It was only a minority that handed in any work.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, We are teaching at beginning undergraduate level. The courses are mostly in computer science and programming.

Answer (score 2):

I was involved in teaching such a class a few years ago and I would say that this approach is better than nothing, but most of the times there might be better options. Keep in mind that all of this is anecdotal and I might misremember things.

### The setting

The situation was a sequence of some large "mathematics for engineering students" classes. The first problem was that this was taught by people from the maths-department (including me), but the engineering department effectively had the final say on anything not related to the actual mathematics. And for that class they insisted (and we definitely tried to convince them otherwise), that we were not to force the students to do anything apart from the absolute minimum.

Specifically the requirement was that any student should be realistically able to get the highest possible grade by just attending and acing the final exam, because that was how all of their other classes were run. The net result of course was that a lot of students (not all, but certainly a large percentage) completely ignored the class until a few days before the exam, crammed whatever they could and then either barely passed or failed and tried the same approach next time.

Even of those that passed, many forgot most of what the learned immediately afterwards, which was an additional problem, since later classes relied on material from the earlier ones (e.g. dealing with systems of linear ODEs in semester 2 needs eigenvalues from semester 1.).

The second problem was that the class was indeed large (close to 1k students enrolled in some years), so the ratio of TA-time per student was also severly limited. Even if we would have had the money to hire more, we would quickly have run out of capable people to hire. So we had enough TAs to hold weekly exercise classes of about 30-40 people each, but e.g. not enough to grade problems regularly. (And we always stressed the mathematical approach to problems, not the numerical calculations, which meant that machine grading was not a good option).

### The approach

With these constraints, the solution we came up (which was the one thing the engineering department allowed us to do) was indeed bonus points for the exam, totalling to a maximum of something like 10% of the grade.

The explicit goal here was purely to boost engagement, without straining our resources too much. So the metric for the students was "reasonable attempts" at solving a problem, even if the result was wrong or the solution incomplete. We varied the details a bit between the classes but roughly the idea was that each week the students would self-report to which problems they had something on and the TAs would spot check this and have some present their solutions in class, more or less at random. But they were told to be lenient.

Anyone who at least tried 50% of the problems and presented one attempt in class got some of the bonus points, up to the full points for 100% of them (there were some optional problems, so it was possible to get 100% even when missing some).

### Some results

It is always hard to evaluate such a system and we did not attempt a scientific study. But the overall grades increased slightly after introducing it, but it is hard to conclude that this was not due to differences in the difficulty of the exams.

The actual exams of people who got bonus points were generally better than
the exams of those that did not get them, but that also might have been self-selecting.

The attendance in problem classes certainly went up, as did general student participation, but there still was a sizable minority that only showed up to miserably fail the exam.

Most of the students liked the system. It probably also helped that most that tried were able to obtain all of the bonus points with a managable amount of work.

There was a lot of blatant copying and questionable "attempts". We fully expected this but reasoned that even someone who only copies at least has to spend some time looking at the problem and that it is impossible to fully police something like that. So we only intervened if it got so blatant that others complained.

### Some things to keep in mind

The administrative side of things should not be underestimated. Even if there is no actual grading and your university supplies a usable system for keeping track of the raw numbers, they have to be entered by someone and now that it suddenly matters there will be a continuous stream of emails that need to be dealt with (e.g. correcting mistakes, accounting for illnesses). Accounting for bonus points in the exam is also another extra step.

Depending on how you implement the system there might also be unintended side-effects. If people think that there is something to be gained from gaming the system, some people will try to game the system. Sometimes people only game themselves (copying solutions and then studying before the exam is probably more work than attempting the problems directly), but you still need to be careful that no-one sees the system as unfair.

As a particular example, initially we let people hand in what they did directly before class to minimize workload. Since the classes were spread over the week, that lead to people in the later classes attend the earlier ones, get the solutions from there, and then present them in the latter classes. People complained and we had to resort to having everyone hand in their attempts at solutions in the beginning of the week.

### tl;dr

Such a system can work and surely beats doing nothing, but depending on the circumstances, there are often better options if you have the ressources.

Answer (score 0):

There is a course design that goes something like this:

> Here is a bunch of information and some suggested activities. You can take it or leave it. And, by the way, every couple of months we will give you an exam that can affect the rest of your life. Good luck.

There is another course design that actually cares about how students do and helps them to achieve their best results. This requires a bit (lot) of prodding with required exercise and projects along with points toward grades and individual feedback.

I predict that the change you suggest, if you use the first design, will have little effect since there is too much elapsed time between the exercise "advice" and the sort of magical awarding of points. There is little "in the moment" motivation.

Sure, it will work with a few students, but they don't need such things anyway. The ones you need to actually "teach" are the ones that don't find everything you say completely trivial and obvious. But for those who really need your actual guidance, not so much.

At a minimum, give the points when the work is done, not later when the exam is taken. And inform the student that the points are "in the bag".

Sorry to be so harsh, but I think laissez-faire teaching isn't really teaching at all. Those who thrive don't really need you.

I hope that your system doesn't force this sort of thing on you with too-large classes and no help.

A better plan would be to actually require that those exercises be done and submitted, with a given number of points, known in advance and earned or lost at given deadlines. My personal practice is to make such things the major part of any course grade with exams having much less influence. People learn by doing things that reinforce learning, not by just sitting exams that they can cram for with little long term learning possible.

The path to success needs to be well marked with achievable goals that the student can use as signposts to success. It should never be necessary for a student to wonder how they are doing. It should be a seemingly random process depending much on things like which particular questions are asked on an exam vs which particular things the student focused on.

See the book [*The Art of Changing the Brain*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1579220541) by Zull for how the brain, and thus learning, actually works. This book was once gifted to every participant in a major Computer Science Education conference (SIGCSE) by one of the major tech companies. I can't remember which.